# NPM hangs in command prompt but work's on powershell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm, command-prompt

I did a fresh install of NodeJs v8.9.1 on a Windows 10 computer, with NodeJs 64 bit installer. I restarted the computer. I can see the path variable pointing at nodejs folder in Program Files.

The problem is when I run `npm -v` in command prompt, the command hangs without any output on console. But when I run the same command on Windows PowerShell console, everything works fine.

Some more information:

1. The same computer has Gitlab-Runner Shell Executer installed as a service on it.
2. There are multiple administrator on this computer, these administrator are from an AD.
3. This computer is registered in AD.

I am not sure if the above information are relevant, but a different Windows 10 computer without the above configuration/customization have no issues running `npm -v` in command prompt.

I have tried fresh installation multiple times. Let me know if you need some more information.

---

**Update:**

Powershell:

```
> get-command npm

CommandType     Name        Version    Source
-----------     ----        -------    ------
Application     npm.cmd     0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

Command Prompt:

```
> where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

Comment: Does PATH point to the same folder in PS and CMD?

Comment: See the current update. This is what I get from these console

Comment: Try a new shell instance via `cmd /c npm.cmd -v`. Also try a new console via `start npm.cmd -v`.

Comment: With both of these command a new npm prompt opens but the moment it opens it hangs. It is not accepting any inputs.

Comment: This is weird because there's no such thing as "PowerShell console" vs a "CMD console". They are both console clients that use a standard Windows console host, conhost.exe, and standard console I/O via the condrv.sys device driver. Moreover, to run npm.cmd, PowerShell will basically have to execute it via `cmd.exe /c npm.cmd`. So what's different about how CMD is being run in one case compared to the other? Try adding the /d option to prevent running autorun commands, e.g. `cmd /d /c npm.cmd -v`.

Comment: @eryksun Is it possible the command precedence is different causing confusion for the cmd interpreter?

Comment: if you run from command prompt, are you using 64- or 32-bit cmd.exe? (in task manager you should see either `cmd.exe *32` or just `cmd.exe`

Comment: I am running a 64 bit version of node in cmd.exe